# Detecting whether a string contains non-letters

Tags: python, string

How can I write a function that detects whether a string has non-letter characters in it?

Something like:

```
def detection(a):
    if !"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM" in a:
        return True
    else:
        return False
print detection("blablabla.bla")
```

Comment: It depends on what your definition of "letters" is. If it only concerns ASCII, then Martijn's answer is OK. But what about unicode? Aren't characters like ä, é and ŝ (just to name a few) also letters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`str.isalpha()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha); it only returns `True` if *all* characters in a string are letters. Negate the result with `not`; if `object.isalpha()` returns `True` (*only* letters in the string) then `not object.isalpha()` returns `False`, and vice versa:

```
def detection(string):
    return not string.isalpha()
```

Demo:

```
>>> def detection(string):
...     return not string.isalpha()
... 
>>> detection('jfiopafbjk')
False
>>> detection('42jfiopafbjk')
True
>>> detection('jfiopafbjk42')
True
>>> detection('jfiop42afbjk')
True
```

Comment: Fan here. you rock :-)

Comment: or he can use regex .;)

Comment: @AvinashBabu: yet a regex is going be more costly both in terms of performance and understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The approach your pseudocode attempts could be written as follows:

```
from string import ascii_letters

def detection(s, valid=set(ascii_letters)):
    """Whether or not s contains only characters in valid."""
    return all(c in valid for c in s)
```

This uses `string.ascii_letters` to define valid characters (rather than write out your own string literal), a `set` to provide efficient (`O(1)`) membership testing and `all` with a generator expression to evaluate all characters `c` in the string `s`.

Given that `str.isalpha` already exists, though, this is reinventing the wheel.